# right way to clear SWR cache

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swr

SWR recommends using

```
mutate(
  key => true, // which cache keys are updated
  undefined, // update cache data to `undefined`
  { revalidate: false } // do not revalidate
)
```

to clear cache. And I can not decide between

```
import {mutate} from "swr"
```

and

```
const {mutate} = useSWRConfig()
```

which is better in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the cache using SWR, both methods achieve the same result, and the choice between them depends on your preference and usage pattern.

via mutate from `swr` directly

```
import { mutate } from 'swr';

mutate(
  key => true, // which cache keys are updated
  undefined,   // update cache data to `undefined`
  { revalidate: false } // do not revalidate
);
```

via mutate from `useSWRConfig`

```
import { useSWRConfig } from 'swr';

const { mutate } = useSWRConfig();

mutate(
  key => true, // which cache keys are updated
  undefined,   // update cache data to `undefined`
  { revalidate: false } // do not revalidate
);
```

The primary difference is the source of the mutate function just

Direct Import `import { mutate } from` 'swr'

**Pros-** More concise, especially if you only need the mutate function.
**Cons-** Adds an extra import.

with `useSWRConfig` `hook (const { mutate } = useSWRConfig())`

**Pros-** Integrates with the hook-based pattern of SWR. would be useful if you are already using `useSWRConfig` for other purposes in your application
**Cons-** Slightly longer syntax. so i would recommend Choosing the one that fits better with the overall structure and style of your code. If you are not using the `useSWRConfig` hook elsewhere in your application, the direct import might be more straightforward. If you are already using the hook, it might make sense to stick with it for consistency.